# UIView With Pointed Edges

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to make a UIView with pointed edges like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0WEU.png). Did some searching around and found some questions with slanting just one edge like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292743/creating-a-container-with-a-slanted-edge) one but can't find an answer with intersecting (points) edges like the one in the picture that dynamically sizes based on the UIView height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Rob's answer to create something like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class PointedView: UIView
{
    @IBInspectable
    /// Percentage of the slant based on the width
    var slopeFactor: CGFloat = 15
    {
        didSet
        {
            updatePath()
        }
    }
    
    private let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0
        
        // with masks, the color of the shape layer doesn’t matter;
        // it only uses the alpha channel; the color of the view is
        // dictate by its background color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
    
    private func updatePath()
    {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        // Start from x = 0 but the mid point of y of the view
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.midY))
        
        // Calculate the slant based on the slopeFactor
        let slantEndX = bounds.maxX * (slopeFactor / 100)
        
        // Create the top slanting line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: slantEndX, y: bounds.minY))
        
        // Straight line from end of slant to the end of the view
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        
        // Straight line to come down to the bottom, perpendicular to view
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        
        // Go back to the slant end position but from the bottom
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: slantEndX, y: bounds.maxY))
        
        // Close path back to where you started
        path.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

The end result should give you a view close to what you which can be modified on the storyboard

[image: Custom UIView with pointed edge tag view iOS swift]

And can also be created using code, here is a frame example since the storyboard showed its compatibility with autolayout

```
private func createPointedView()
{
    let pointedView = PointedView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                y: 0,
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 60))
    
    pointedView.backgroundColor = .red
    pointedView.slopeFactor = 50
    pointedView.center = view.center
    
    view.addSubview(pointedView)
}
```